# How to add particular internal tester's group via azure devops pipeline in testflight release

Tags: azure-pipelines, testflight

I am able to release a ios app through azure devops to testflight
I have multiple group of internal testers. I would like to add one or more specific internal testers group in a the release.
I have found ways to add external tester's group in a release.
Not able to find any solution to add internal testers via azure devops pipline.

so far I have used
AppStoreRelease@1
it has option to add external tester's group but couldn't find any thing about adding internal testers group

I saw this
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/distribution/stores/apple/testflight_internal
I couldn't understand it much.(I am very new to devops and azure).
I want to do it through yml file.

Thanks

This is what I am using and it's able to publish the app on testflight. but I have to go to apple's developer's portal and manually add the internal tester's group.

```
- stage: AppStoreRelease
  jobs:
  - job: ReleaseJob
    displayName: Distribute To TestFlight
    steps:
    - task: AppStoreRelease@1
      inputs:
        authType: 'ApiKey'
        apiKeyId: 'apiKeyId'
        apiKeyIssuerId: 'apiKeyIssuerId'
        apitoken: 'apiToken'
        releaseTrack: 'TestFlight'
        appIdentifier: 'com.app.identifier'
        appType: 'iOS'
        ipaPath: '$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)/**/*.ipa'
        shouldSkipWaitingForProcessing: true
        shouldSkipSubmission: true
        releaseNotes: 'whatToTest.txt'
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no method on the **`AppStoreRelease@1`** task to specify particular internal testers groups.

To specify particular internal testers groups, you can try like as below:

1. Keep the current configurations on the **`AppStoreRelease@1`** task to let it can release your iOS app as usual.
2. After the **`AppStoreRelease@1`** task, add a script task (such as [Bash](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/bash-v3?view=azure-pipelines), [PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/powershell-v2?view=azure-pipelines) or [CmdLine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/cmd-line-v2?view=azure-pipelines)) to call the TestFlight related API ([**Adding and Removing Builds and Testers**](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreconnectapi/prerelease_versions_and_beta_testers/beta_groups#2973761)) to add or remove testers groups from the app.

By this way, after the **`AppStoreRelease@1`** task successfully releases the app, the subsequent script task will run and call the related API to assign groups.

---

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. 
Let me try this.